# Database Master detail relation and datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, master-detail

I looking simplest way to implement master detail winforms app (using mainly data grid view) 
It should interact with database, handling database exceptions (eg unique index violation) and work in multi user environment (concurrent updates etc)

I know how to do that with data set and relation between tables, not sure what is best approach if this has to work with database
Few years ago I did similar app base on business objects and stored procedures but I believe this can be done easier this days.

Appreciate if someone can share general ideas or share some links to webpages discribing that in detail

Comment: Would this be really easiest / quickiest? I just need quickly develop few interferes - currently users edit database directly. I think dataset / datatable should be able to manage that. I don't want tulo build "big app". I don't want to use business objects if not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **DataSet** combined with a **BindingSource** could be, what you are looking for.
For a simple master/detail view it provides everything you need.

- Connection management.
- Certain degree of error handling.
- Binding every kind of control to your data
- In simple cases, like yours, almost everything can be done in Visual Studio GUI
- Data-navigation controls

[BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[BindingNavigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for tip - I think Ive managed to do what I need

Ive found below article quite informative:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3805/Inserting-relational-data-using-DataSet-and-DataAd